# How to add a loader to handle .mpd and .mp4s filetype (dash media files)?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-component, nuxt.js, video.js

I have a question: how to add dash assets (i.e., file_dash.mpd, file_1.m4s, and file_init.mp4) to be included?

The dash resources are valid; I tested teh media set (file_dash.mpd, file_1.m4s, and file_init.mp4) in a static HTML file.

Workaround: loading the files from an external https-resource, e.g., src="https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps.mpd" type="application/dash+xml" ) works fine.

Solution? I think possibly, webpack needs to be extended https://nuxtjs.org/faq/extend-webpack/ but I do not know how to do this.

Any help much appreciated!

**Snippet**

```
<section data-sr id="dash" class="dash u-full-width">
    <div class="video-background">
      <div class="video-wrap">
        <video id="bgvid" autoplay loop loop="true" muted controls="false" setScheduleWhilePaused="true"
          setFastSwitchEnabled="true">
<!--        <source src="https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps.mpd" type="application/dash+xml" /> -->
        <source src="~/assets/media/tangent_dash.mpd" type="application/dash+xml" />
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

**Error message thrown by npm run dev**

```
ERROR  in ./assets/media/tangent_dash.mpd                                                    friendly-errors 20:39:50

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)                                                   friendly-errors 20:39:50
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
| <!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 1.0.1-rev0-gd8538e8a-master at 2020-12-30T18:06:34.544Z -->
| <MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.500S" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H0M7.166S" maxSegmentDuration="PT0H0M7.167S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011,http://dashif.org/guidelines/dash264">
                                                                                              friendly-errors 20:39:50
 @ ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/@nuxt/components/dist/loader.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/index.vue?vue&type=template&id=2a183b29& 29:23-63
 @ ./pages/index.vue?vue&type=template&id=2a183b29&
 @ ./pages/index.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/router.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js eventsource-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&path=%2F__webpack_hmr%2Fclient&name=client ./.nuxt/client.js
                                                                                              friendly-errors 20:39:50
ℹ Waiting for file changes                                                                                    20:39:50
ℹ Memory usage: 206 MB (RSS: 410 MB)                                                                          20:39:50
ℹ Listening on: http://localhost:3000/                                                                        20:39:50

 ERROR  [Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)                      20:41:25
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
| <!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 1.0.1-rev0-gd8538e8a-master at 2020-12-30T18:06:34.544Z -->
| <MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.500S" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H0M7.166S" maxSegmentDuration="PT0H0M7.167S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011,http://dashif.org/guidelines/dash264">"

found in

---> <Hello> at pages/index.vue
       <Nuxt>
         <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue
           <Root>
```

**index.vue file**

```
<template>

<section data-sr id="dash" class="dash u-full-width">
    <div class="video-background">
      <div class="video-wrap">
        <video id="bgvid" autoplay loop loop="true" muted controls="false" setScheduleWhilePaused="true"
          setFastSwitchEnabled="true">
<!--        <source src="https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps.mpd" type="application/dash+xml" /> -->
        <source src="~/assets/media/tangent_dash.mpd" type="application/dash+xml" />
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</template>

<script>
import '../node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.css'
import videojs from 'video.js'
import 'dashjs'
import 'videojs-contrib-dash'

export default {
  name: 'hello',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is here: https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html

> To answer this question, we first need to understand how Webpack deals with static assets. In *.vue components, all your templates and CSS are parsed by vue-html-loader and css-loader to look for asset URLs. For example, in  and background: url(./logo.png), "./logo.png" is a relative asset path and will be resolved by Webpack as a module dependency.

> Because logo.png is not JavaScript, when treated as a module dependency, we need to use url-loader and file-loader to process it. This template has already configured these loaders for you, so you get features such as filename fingerprinting and conditional base64 inlining for free, while being able to use relative/module paths without worrying about deployment.

I assume that what you need is "Real" Static Assets (it's explained at the same link), as there is no point to "pack" your media file along with JS.

> In comparison, files in static/ are not processed by Webpack at all: they are directly copied to their final destination as-is, with the same filename. You must reference these files using absolute paths, which is determined by joining build.assetsPublicPath and build.assetsSubDirectory in config.js.

Alternatively you can change your nuxt configuration to load audio files as described in [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/webpack-audio-files):

> You need to extend its default configuration in nuxt.config.js:

```js
export default {
  build: {
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(ogg|mp3|wav|mpe?g|OTHER_AUDIO_FILE_EXTENSIONS_LIKE_MP4S)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]'
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Just replace `OTHER_AUDIO_FILE_EXTENSIONS_LIKE_MP4S` with extensions you want to load.

Comment: Thank you!
I fiddeled a bit to make it work for a video resource.
And the files did not end up in the desired assets subdirectory. Only the mpd file was copied over to that directory, and the others were in the root dir. Below are the changes, inspired by this answer that I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with changing the template video tag to:

```
<source src="tangent_dash.mpd" type="application/dash+xml" />
```

and adding the following to the nuxt.config.js file:

```
build: {
    loaders: {
      vue: {
        transformAssetUrls: {
          video: 'src'
        }
      }
    },

    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(mpd|mp4|m4s)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]'
        }
      })
    }
```